# How to upgrade my existing .net project to asp.net core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am in the middle of the development of a project.I am using asp.net framework 4.5.So far what I have developed, I have to publish it on a Linux server. So i fount that, I will have to upgrade my existing project to **ASP.NET Core 1.0** in order to publish on Linux server. Can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: There is no straightforward upgrade path, it'S completely different framework that are not compatible with each other. The ASP.NET Core team did a great effort in making most of the common classes same to use (Controller Base class etc.), but its still a different path and you have to go with a migration (which means way bigger changes may be required to your code, depending on what exactly you use).

Comment: The HTTP Request pipeline is completely different and no previous ASP.NET webstack, so anything that used to intercept requests etc won't work. Anything that used to read configuration from web.config, will need to be rewritten to use the new injectable Options pattern. Controllers etc won't need big changes, but everything that goes deeper into the system than controller and action will needed to migrated for versions that support ASP.NET Core and not all libraries that used to intercept the pipeline are ported yet for ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 3):

You may encounter a couple of issues and looks for different solutions but a general guide can be found here: [Migrating From ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/mvc.html)

For specific errors when the general migration will be done, it's worth to take a look at ASP.NET Core's GitHub page as a lot of issues that can occur during migration is described there.

Comment: I have read already read this article.But i am not sure how my existing project is going to be upgraded.

Comment: @rafat, there is no migration wizard as they are two different platforms. Before Microsoft publishes new bits to minimize the gaps, you will have to carefully learn ASP.NET Core, create a new project and cut-and-paste.